# If section is always contractible, is that convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

Consider compact set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$, whose intersection with any $(d-1)$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^d$ is contractible. Then, is such $\Omega$ convex?

Comment: @amsmath - yes, to be exact it is contractible. I edited the question. sorry again.

Comment: This is trivially true for $d=2$ as contractible subsets of $\mathbb R^1$ are intervals.

Answer (score 3):

No. Consider a large sphere, with a smaller sphere removed from the centre. The intersection with any plane is still connected (it will be a circle or an annulus). But this is clearly not a convex set. Similar higher-dimensional analogues can be found.

Comment: I should have added condition of contractibility, I forgot to write that. Good observation and sorry for missing that.

Comment: Only works for $d > 2$.